# What does removing unused css mean in google audit?

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am using google's audit and its tells me to remove unused CSS. I don't know if that css is for just that page or the whole site. The CSS might be there but not needed on that page but another page. Can someone tell me how this works?

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you to remove unneeded CSS for that page.

However you have rightly pointed out the flaw in this suggestion as it only takes into account the current page (in it's initial state, obviously if you have a pop-out menu it won't gather the CSS for that).

Think of it more as a guideline of making sure you don't send the whole of Bootstrap just for the grid and column layouts for example.

Overall this is very difficult to fix, just use the `coverage` section on the performance tab in Developer tools to make sure you don't have any massively bloated CSS files and you will be fine.

Obviously reduce your unused CSS if it is easy to do so.

The only other thing that this point covers (in it's description, not as part of it's monitoring) is deferring non-essential CSS.

You should defer any Style Sheets that are not required for rendering 'above the fold' content (and inline your 'above the fold' CSS).

This point is also covered in 'Eliminate Render Blocking Resources' so I never quite get why they add the suggestion under this part as well but I have added it for completeness.

I find this rule was good at guiding me when designing a theme from the ground up as it made me seperate global CSS and page CSS more effectively.

Unless your site is scoring 98 / 100 (or you have hundreds of kilobytes of CSS) and you want to squeeze that last little bit of performance out of the site, simply minify and combine your CSS files and ignore this point.

Comment: the whole process has been difficult. I have already combined CSS and JS using a plugin called JCH for wordpress. Now its telling me those files are render-blocking.

Comment: Yes so render blocking is a different bit as I discussed above. Open a different question about that if you can't find the answer by googling it. The line 'You defer any Style Sheets that....' covers the two steps to fix that problem (defer most of the CSS, inline the critical CSS). It isn't an easy process to do it properly, especially when fixing a theme not designed for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Google's audit tool compares the entire stylesheet against the current URL and then tells you how much of it is actually not used by the browser.

The browser however still needs to download the entire file and then match all CSS selectors that apply to the current URL.

There are many ways to deal with this, but I find it the easiest to use an external API tool like [Splitcss](https://splitcss.com) that does this for you on URL basis.

If you have only a few URL patterns in your web application, you can use some CLI tools like [purgecss](https://purgecss.com/) or [uncss](https://uncss-online.com/).